# xmlns attributes in Android layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-menu

I'm well-versed in Java, but not that familiar with XML. In many of my layout/menu files, I have these lines:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Somtimes I have all of them, sometimes just some combination. Could somebody give an explanation towards these three lines? Under which scenarios should we include each one? So far I have just been adding them in whenever Android Studio prompts me, but I would like to understand the use cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could somebody give an explanation towards these three lines?

Each declare a different XML namespace (`android`, `app`, and `tools`, respectively).

> Under which scenarios should we include each one?

If your XML file has one or more attributes prefixed with `android:`, you need to declare the `android` namespace. Many XML files will have these, from framework-defined runtime attributes.

If your XML file has one or more attributes prefixed with `app:`, you need to declare the `app` namespace. Some layout and menu resource files will have these, from library-defined attributes.

If your XML file has one or more attributes prefixed with `tools:`, you need to declare the `tools` namespace. Few resource files will have these, from attributes used to help the build tools understand what to do.

Comment: Dang man I see you everywhere on SO. How long do you spend a day on this site? Thanks for the answer btw